# display the empno,ename of employees who where count of job>1

Tags: oracle, greatest-n-per-group

```
EMPNO   ENAME   JOB         MGR     HIREDATE     SAL    COMM    DEPTNO
7839    KING    PRESIDENT     -     11/17/1981  5000    -        10
7698    BLAKE   MANAGER     7839    05/01/1981  2850    -        30
7782    CLARK   MANAGER     7839    06/09/1981  2450    -        10
7566    JONES   MANAGER     7839    04/02/1981  2975    -        20
7788    SCOTT   ANALYST     7566    12/09/1982  3000    -        20
7902    FORD    ANALYST     7566    12/03/1981  3000    -        20
7369    SMITH   CLERK       7902    12/17/1980  800     -        20
7499    ALLEN   SALESMAN    7698    02/20/1981  1600    300      30
7521    WARD    SALESMAN    7698    02/22/1981  1250    500      30
```

---

In the default table emp, in oracle 11g, i need to display the names of those employees with their emp no , where the job is greater than 1.

Like in the table there are 3 managers and 2 salesman which should be printed with ename,emp. Job like president which is just 1 should be omitted.

Comment: please always just tag one RDBMS

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: did i get you right: CLERK should not be returned by the query, but ANALYST should be returned?

Answer (score 1):

Like below, you will need a subquery to select job from emp where you can calculate the count and check if its greater than 1. Before the subquery you will select EMPNO and ENAME to display from emp.

```
    SELECT EMPNO, ENAME
    FROM emp 
    WHERE JOB IN (SELECT JOB
    FROM emp
    GROUP BY JOB 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The subselect will just return JOBs which occur more than 1 time. 
The outer select will now just return EMPNOs which are in this subset of JOBs

```
SELECT EMPNO,ENAME
  FROM emp
 WHERE JOB IN (SELECT JOB
                 FROM emp
             GROUP BY JOB 
               HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try GROUP BY :

```
SELECT empno,ename, count(job)
FROM emp
GROUP BY job
HAVING count(job)>1
```

COUNT(JOB) : the number of employees with the same job
GROUP BY Job : group the results by job eg. 3 managers and 2 salesman....